# Data binding between text and graphical representation

Tags: javascript, parsing, data-structures, tokenize

We are developing new app written purely on a client side using JavaScript. There will be some text editor and graphics that are created based on that text. That would be easy, but we need do it both ways. There will be tools to modify graphics directly like move elements around and other operations. These changes should be written back to the text representation.

I am basically thinking about two approaches upon change in graphics:

- regenerate whole text top to bottom
- somehow make a mapping of text portions against graphical elements

First approach is probably easier, but it smells with double logic and makes maintanability quite hard.

Second approach is definitely harder to implement. It would probably require some tokenizer to keep every text element in an object and link that object to graphics. Upon change of the graphics it would update token...but what's next? How could I update original text based on the token? Are there some generic tokenizers that can recreate text from their representation when something changes?

**Edit**: Basically what I am looking for is some approach to create tokenized representation of parsed text that can be updated later followed by update to original text.

Comment: Are you averse to using a library like fabric.js? Pretty broad question, otherwise.

Comment: I don't follow how can be fabric.js useful. I am not asking about drawing, this is basically about creating data structure from a parsed text a then be able to update that text based on some minor changes to the parsed form.